# Does not send the form in a modal window. Why?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, forms

Site pulled on WordPress.

The usual forms on the site work, but in the modal window does not.

The console shows nothing. The send button does not respond.

Broke my head. Help find the problem.

Code JS:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function () {

    var formID = $(this).attr('id');

    var formNm = $('#' + formID);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'mail.php',
        data: formNm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {

            $(formNm).html(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {

            $(formNm).html(error);         
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Html form on pop-up (id different):

```
   <form action="mail.php" method="POST" id="formModal1">
                        <input type="text" name="t-number" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required />
                        <input type="submit" placeholder="Получить консультацию" />
                    </form>
```

Php :

```
<?php
      if (isset($_POST['t-number'])) {$phone = $_POST['t-number'];}
      if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email'];}



    $address = "";


    $mes = "Тема: Заказ обратного звонка!\nТелефон: $phone\nE-mail: $email";

    $sub='Заказ';
    $mail='Заказ <Центр юридической помощи>';
    $send = mail ($address,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$mail");

    ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On');

    ?>
```

Comment: Is your network request even being processed? Chances are this is failing on the server side. You can debug this by clicking through requests in the Network tab of your console. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/#analyze

Comment: Maybe use the form id in your `on()` function instead of just "form"?

Comment: You need to narrow this down to a client-side or server-side issue

Comment: When I click on submit in the modal window the network does not react in any way. Nothing happens at all.